# spark sql dataframe calls the whole function again during the save

Tags: python, apache-spark, time-series

I'm trying to hypertune a sarimax model with spark api using pandas UDF function
**function call code**

```
results = (df_part.groupby('LCLid').apply(forecast_consumption))
results.persist()
results.show()
```

after the training I'm trying to save the results in mongodb, but when I run the following code for save. It again calls the forecast_consumption function and again computes the result taking much more time than the above code.
**writing to mongodb code**

```
results.write.format("mongo").mode("append").save()
```

Is there a way to directly save the computed results without computing the whole training process again?

Comment: how are you sure that it is recalculated? the `.persist()` before the `.show()` should have marked the dataframe to cache.

Comment: Yes I'm sure bcz at the anaconda terminal it shows the sarimax calculation again when I write it to db

Comment: your code is identical to pandas, yet you write pyspark and spark-api throughout. are you using pyspark-pandas that was introduced recently? if that's the case, does it not require conversion to a spark dataframe post calculations?

Comment: results in the code is of type pyspark sql dataframe. I've already checked it